# C# Running command with ScpClient

Tags: c#

I am trying to upload file with ScpClient, however, I need to run a command first. I do not find any "write/run" method in ScpClient. Is there any way to do it?

```
private void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var auth1 = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username.Text, password.Text);
    var auth2 = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(username.Text);
    ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo(host.Text, username.Text, auth1, auth2);

    string source = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\111.txt";
    string destination = @"/flash/data0";


    scpclient = new ScpClient(conInfo);
    scpclient.Connect();
    /*
    need to run a command 
    */        
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(source);
    scpclient.Upload(file, destination);           
}
```

Comment: please share code snippet what ever you already tried and specify which version of c# you are use ?

Comment: I upload the part of code I tried before.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET). Then you might try to reuse your connection and instantiate SshClient to run commands:

```cs
    var auth1 = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username.Text, password.Text);
    var auth2 = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(username.Text);
    ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo(host.Text, username.Text, auth1, auth2);
...
        //first you run your command
    var sshClient = new SshClient(conInfo);
    sshClient.Connect();
    var cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("ls");
    var r = cmd.Execute();

    //then you reuse credentials and upload your file

    var scpclient = new ScpClient(conInfo);
    scpclient.Connect(); // note you have to .connect() for the second time. this is due to library not providing any obvious ways to share session between clients
    /*
    need to run a command 
    */
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo("d:\\1.txt");
    scpclient.Upload(file, "~");
}
```

the way library is written seems to force into establishing two connections here, this can probably be overcome by inheriting from `BaseClient` and implementing your actions (most likely you just need to copy relevant methods from respective classes)

---

**UPD** as we already established, you want to keep your connection alive between operations, and therefore avoid doing the above. This is somewhat tricky as the library hides internal `Session` object and does not allow you to reuse it.
You however can still inherit from one of the clients (`ScpClient` seemed like a good base to start) and implement the `CreateCommand` method like so:

```cs
public class RunAndUpload : ScpClient
{   
    public RunAndUpload(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
            : base(connectionInfo)
    {
    }

    public SshCommand CreateCommand(string commandText)
    {
        var pi = typeof(RunAndUpload).GetProperty("Session", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var command = (SshCommand)typeof(SshCommand).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)[0].Invoke(new object[] {pi.GetValue(this), commandText, this.ConnectionInfo.Encoding} );       
        return command;
    }
}
```

you will notice I had to opt for reflection just to instantiate the `SshCommand` (as it's constructor is internal to the library and normally would not be exposed). Once you past the stage of obtaining a command instance - it should all be smooth from there:

```cs
    using(var sshClient = new RunAndUpload(conInfo)) {
        sshClient.Connect();        
        var cmd = sshClient.CreateCommand("ls");
        var r = cmd.Execute();
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo("d:\\1.txt");
        sshClient.Upload(file, "1.txt");
    }
```

hopefully that works for you

Comment: Can I use SshClient to upload a file? I cannot find this method in SshClient, therefore, I choose ScpClient. However, I need to  run a command before I upload it.

Comment: I updated the answer. It seems you cannot use one client class for both actions, therefore you have to go connect twice - first to execute commands and then to upload files

Comment: Do you require both actions performed under same SSH session though?

Comment: Yes, I need to do it under same SSH session.

Comment: Is it possible to use ShellStream instead of Sshcommand? I do not know why the program will stuck when the code run to "var cmd = sshClient.CreateCommand("ls");".

Comment: I don't think `ShellStream` will allow you to upload files - it seems to be a terminal representation. The code above works for me, maybe update your question with reproducible example?

Comment: I mean use ShellStream to execute a command. Is it possible? I built up the function  with winform. The winform would stuck when I ran var `cmd = sshClient.CreateCommand("ls");`

Comment: Is it possible to inherit `SshClient` and implement "Upload" from `ScpClinet`? I guess there is a security setting, therefore, I cannot use the method you provide.

Comment: unfortunately, from what i can see in the source - it's way too complicated to reimplement the `Upload` method somewhere else. i'd say you might need to look at other solutions if this doesn't work for you

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to inherit `ScpClient` and implement "Write" from `ShellStream`? Sorry that I am not familiar with this one.

Comment: Likely not much easier than the previous one.  You might have better luck forking the library source code and implementing the exact client you need

Comment: Appreciate your answer and help!

Answer (score 0):

SSH.NET is limited in some OpenSSH keys for this reason I have created a custom version of **Microsoft.DevTunnels.Ssh** to solve my issues.

[check this one](https://github.com/aliasadidev/ssh-scp)